# ASP.NET Core identify give null value (identify)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a class called `ApplicationUser` that inherits from `IdentityUser`, and I use that `ApplicationUser` in a controller to show email address in view.

Controller code:

```
public IActionResult test()
{
        //var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        //var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        //ApplicationUser x = _db.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefault( x=>x.Id==claim.Type);

        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);// will give the user's userId
        var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name); // will give the user's userName
       
        // For ASP.NET Core <= 3.1
        ApplicationUser applicationUser =  _db.ApplicationUser.Find(userName);
        string userEmail = applicationUser?.Email;

        return View(applicationUser);
}
```

and this is view markup:

```
@model Store.Models.ApplicationUser

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>test</h1>

<h1>@Model.FullName</h1>
```

When I run the page, I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Model.get returned null

and the ApplicationUser returns null.

Comment: IMHO just use the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` service & `.GetUserAsync(this.User)`. But maybe you should `[Authorise]` to block access to that page when not logged in.

Comment: What is the value of `ApplicationUser applicationUser` in your action?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your model **`ApplicationUser`** contains property of **`FullName`** ,

in the code below

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser =  _db.ApplicationUser.Find(userName);
string userEmail = applicationUser?.Email;
```

make sure you are getting an instance of **`applicationUser`** before returning it to the **view**.

Answer (score 1):

Your `applicationUser` should not be null when you pass it to the **view**.
You can debug to see if query result from database is null.